# How to quickly sort by calculated criteria in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, sorting

I need to write a query sorting records by dynamically calculated criteria. There is a two-dimensional array of 12x12 in each cell of which the number of points is indicated. The points are distributed along the diagonals (i.e., all elements of the main diagonal give 6 points)

```
+----+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+----+----+----+
| №  | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 |
+----+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+----+----+----+
|  1 | 6 | 4 | 5 | 2 | 7 | 3 | 1 | 6 | 7 |  2 |  5 |  6 |
|  2 | 4 | 6 | 4 | 5 | 2 | 7 | 3 | 1 | 6 |  7 |  2 |  5 |
|  3 | 5 | 4 | 6 | 4 | 5 | 2 | 7 | 3 | 1 |  6 |  7 |  2 |
|  4 | 2 | 5 | 4 | 6 | 4 | 5 | 2 | 7 | 3 |  1 |  6 |  7 |
|  5 | 7 | 2 | 5 | 4 | 6 | 4 | 5 | 2 | 7 |  3 |  1 |  6 |
|  6 | 3 | 7 | 2 | 5 | 4 | 6 | 4 | 5 | 2 |  7 |  3 |  1 |
|  7 | 1 | 3 | 7 | 2 | 5 | 4 | 6 | 4 | 5 |  2 |  7 |  3 |
|  8 | 6 | 1 | 3 | 7 | 2 | 5 | 4 | 6 | 4 |  5 |  2 |  7 |
|  9 | 7 | 6 | 1 | 3 | 7 | 2 | 5 | 4 | 6 |  4 |  5 |  2 |
| 10 | 2 | 7 | 6 | 1 | 3 | 7 | 2 | 5 | 4 |  6 |  4 |  5 |
| 11 | 5 | 2 | 7 | 6 | 1 | 3 | 7 | 2 | 5 |  4 |  6 |  4 |
| 12 | 6 | 5 | 2 | 7 | 6 | 1 | 3 | 7 | 2 |  5 |  4 |  6 |
+----+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+----+----+----+
```

There is a table with the results, here is its structure:

```
create table result_schema (
    user_id bigint not null,
    result_1 integer not null,
    result_2 integer not null,
    result_3 integer not null,
    result_4 integer not null,
    result_5 integer not null
);
```

The "result_ *" columns contain the column number from the array. I need write a function for calculating points. The function arguments are: value from the column result_ * and some reference value (index number of the row in the array)

Points must be calculated for each field result_ * and summed, and the result is sorted in descending order.

At the moment, I have written a function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION rank(row integer, column integer) RETURNS integer AS $$
DECLARE
    diagonal_number integer;
BEGIN
    diagonal_number = row - column + 1;
    if (diagonal_number < 1) then
        diagonal_number = abs(diagonal_number) + 2;
    end if;

    case diagonal_number
        when 1, 12  then return 6;
        when 2      then return 4;
        when 3, 11  then return 5;
        when 4, 10  then return 2;
        when 5, 9   then return 7;
        when 6, 8   then return 3;
        when 7      then return 1;
        else
            return 0; -- ERROR!
    end case;
END; $$
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

And here is a query to retrieve data:

```
select user_id, (
    rank(6, result_1) +
    rank(1, result_2) +
    rank(4, result_3) +
    rank(8, result_4) +
    rank(9, result_5)
) as rate 
from result_schema 
where user_id between 1 and 1000 
order by rate desc;
```

There are 5,000,000 items in the table with the results, but the sample passes only 1,000 each. And it takes ~ 700ms. Is there a way to optimize the selection or speed up the search by other means? Can use another DBMS instead of postgres?

Comment: Use a 12X12 lookup-table `{x,y} -->> {value}` {x,y} could be indexed or (part of) a key.

Comment: Please add the definition of your "results"-table to the question, plus some sample data + the expected output.